# Stream of a nested POJOs List to a another POJO LIST

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, pojo

hope someone can help me. I have a POJO with the following structure:

```
public class Invoice{

private String docNum;
private String customer;
private ArrayList<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetails;

/* Getters and setters*/
}
```

And another POJO with the following

```
public class InvoiceDetails{

private String vatGroup;
private Double vatAmount;
private Double amount;

/* Getters and setters*/
}
```

Besides I have a third one with the following

```
public class VatType{

private String vatGroup;
private Double vatAmount;
private Double amount;

/* Getters and setters*/
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to reduce a `List` of `Invoice`to a `List`of  `VatType` grouped by vatGroup. Like de `DISTINCT` clause in `SQL`.
Let's say I have the following List:

```
InvoiceDetails idA1 = new InvoiceDetails("S1", 100.0, 40.0);
InvoiceDetails idA2 = new InvoiceDetails("S2", 140.0, 40.0);
InvoiceDetails idA3 = new InvoiceDetails("A1", 50.0, 10.0);
ArrayList<InvoiceDetails> listA = new ArrayList<>();
listA.add(idA1);
listA.add(idA2);
listA.add(idA3);

Invoice invoiceA = new Invoice();
invoiceA.setDetailList(listA);

InvoiceDetails idB1 = new InvoiceDetails("S1", 200.0, 50.0);
InvoiceDetails idB2 = new InvoiceDetails("S2", 240.0, 50.0);
InvoiceDetails idB2 = new InvoiceDetails("A1", 100.0, 20.0);
ArrayList<InvoiceDetails> listB = new ArrayList<>();
listB.add(idB1);
listB.add(idB2);
listB.add(idB3);


Invoice invoiceB = new Invoice();
invoiceB.setDetailList(listB);

List<Invoice> invoiceList = new ArrayList<>();
invoiceList.add(invoiceA);
invoiceList.add(invoiceB);
```

The expected result would be a `List`of `VatType`with the following items:

```
("S1",300.0,90.0)
("S2",380.0,90.0)
("A1",150.0,30.0)
```

How can I get this list using a `stream`in one shot. Avoiding to iterate through the `Lists`?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the Stream API?

Comment: May be a good idea to extract the common parts from `InvoiceDetailes` and `VatType` into a `CommonClass`, then you can do operations on `List<CommonClass>` and do not have to convert lists vica-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need a [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to create a stream of all `InvoiceDetails` in all `Invoice` in your list. After that you can reduce with the variant of [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) that gets a merge method. Finally `values()` method of `Map` will get a `Collection` of `VatType`:

```
Collection<VatType> values = invoiceList.stream()
        .flatMap(invoices -> invoices.getInvoiceDetails().stream())
        .collect(toMap(InvoiceDetails::getVatGroup, VatType::new, (i1, i2) -> {
            i1.setAmount(i1.getAmount() + i2.getAmount());
            i1.setVatAmount(i1.getVatAmount() + i2.getVatAmount());
            return i1;
        }))
        .values();
```

Where this `VatType` constructor is used:

```
VatType(InvoiceDetails invoiceDetails) {
    vatGroup = invoiceDetails.getVatGroup();
    vatAmount = invoiceDetails.getVatAmount();
    amount = invoiceDetails.getAmount();
}
```

You can easily make a `List` from a `Collection` if you need one:

```
List<VatType> vatTypes = new ArrayList<>(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java stream Function:

```
Function<InvoiceDetails, VatType> myF = t -> new VatType(t.getVatGroup(), t.getVatAmount(), t.getAmount());
```

and then stream than using:

```
List<VatType> myLocations = 
        invoiceList.stream()
        .map(Invoice::getInvoiceDetails)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(myF)
        .collect(Collectors.<VatType>toList());
```

Comment: Thank you ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa It works fine thougth it doesn't _merge_ the values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using Java 8's new features of `List` and `Map`, without streams:

```
Map<String, VatType> map = new HashMap<>();

invoiceList.forEach(i -> i.getDetailList().forEach(d ->
    map.merge(
        d.getVatGroup(),
        new VatType(d.getVatGroup(), d.getVatAmount(), d.getAmount()),
        (left, right) -> {
            left.setAmount(left.getAmount() + right.getAmount());
            left.setVatAmount(left.getVatAmount() + right.getVatAmount());
            return left;
        })));

List<VatType> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

If you could add a constructor to `VatType` that accepts a `InvoiceDetail` instance and a `merge` method that combines two `VatType` instances:

```
public VatType(String vatGroup, Double vatAmount, Double amount) {
    this.vatGroup = vatGroup;
    this.vatAmount = vatAmount;
    this.amount = amount;
}

public VatType(InvoiceDetails details) {
    this(details.getVatGroup(), details.getVatAmount(), details.getAmount());
}

public VatType merge(VatType another) {
    this.vatAmount += another.vatAmount;
    this.amount += another.amount;
    return this;
}
```

Then, you could simplify the first snippet to:

```
Map<String, VatType> map = new HashMap<>();

invoiceList.forEach(i -> i.getDetailList().forEach(d ->
        map.merge(d.getVatGroup(), new VatType(d), VatType::merge)));

List<VatType> result = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: Thank you Federico It's a very interesting alternative way to the streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [dozer library](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) if this is common task in your project.